# Context Management of References Within a Class

Tags: python-3.x, yield, contextmanager, atexit

It seems that `__del__` is a bad option when it comes to cleaning up Python classes, mainly because it isn't always guaranteed to be called. Say I have a process management class, like so:

```
class ProcessCTL(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._procs = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._procs[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, cls):
        self._procs[key] = cls

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._procs.items())

    def __del__(self):
        self.kill_all()

    def start_all(self):
        for _, cls in self:
            cls.start()

    def kill_all(self):
        for _, cls in self:
            cls.kill()
```

that simply keeps a dictionary of references to another Python class that implements `start` and `kill` for a subprocess.

The `ProcessCTL` class can then be used in other classes, like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pctl = ProcessCTL()
        self.pctl['db'] = DBConnection()
        self.pctl.start_all()

    def do_work(self, stmt):
        self.pctl['db'].execute(stmt)
        return self.pctl['db'].fetchall()
```

However, when `Foo` gets deleted, it is not guaranteed that `DBConnection.kill` will ever be called. I could just add another method like `Foo.close` that in turn calls `ProcessCTL.kill_all`, but I don't want to rely on the developer to call `close`, and want to take care of things automatically.

Other options include something like `atexit`, but the problem here is again the the developer might choose to use `Foo` in some weird way, or send a signal that isn't handled by `atexit`, etc.

What is the best way to do "class level" context management of references to other objects such that an instance of `Foo` can be created, and once it is done being used, I am guaranteed that `ProcessCTL.kill_all` will also be called?

I've tried adding `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to `ProcessCTL`, hoping that something like this would be possible:

```
class ProcessCTL(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._procs = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._procs[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, cls):
        self._procs[key] = cls

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._procs.items())

    def __del__(self):
        self.kill_all()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, t, v, e):
        self.kill_all()

    def start_all(self):
        for _, cls in self:
            cls.start()

    def kill_all(self):
        for _, cls in self:
            cls.kill()

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pctl = _get_pctl()

    def _get_pctl():
        with ProcessCTL() as pctl:
            pctl['db'] = DBConnection()
            pctl.start_all()
            yield pctl
```

but `yield` will always return a `generator`, rather than a reference to the created `ProcessCTL` instance.

Comment: You can perhaps use `__enter__(..)` and `__exit__(..)` but still would not ensure that the users will always use the `with` clause. You could perhaps pass a special kwargs into the `__init__(..)` of the class to signal that it was instantiated from a context manager, but that still can be bypassed. In general, I believe, this boils down to discipline.

Comment: BTW, if you'd like to use `yield`s, remember to decorate it with `@contextmanager`. Also, this is typically used for standalone functions rather than classes. Not a great idea to mix the two..

Comment: @UltraInstinct, I've modified the question a but to try to provide an example, but as far as I understand there is no easy way to define a "context managed" class attribute, is there?